# Crear clase y modificar boolean de una propiedad

Tags: javascript, objeto, class, booleano, switch

Acá el error:

```
 ● Clase › crearClaseEmpleado › should return a user constructor that correctly builds empleados objects

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false

       98 |         expect(persona.salario).toBe(4000);
       99 |         expect(persona.tareas).toEqual(['operaciones']);
    > 100 |         expect(persona.jefe).toEqual(true);
          |                              ^
      101 |     });
      102 |     it('should add a task with addTarea', function() {
      103 |         const Empleado = crearClaseEmpleado();
```

Y al segundo ejercicio no le puedo agarrar la mano

> - 

Lo que había hecho acá era :

```
switchJefe(hobby) {
   
  if (Empleado.jefe === false)
      Empleado.jefe = true;
      else
      Empleado.jefe = false;
    }
}
```

Y sigue hasta tercera parte

```
    getTareasPrioritarias(prioridad) {
          // 
    
      
 get Tareas() {
    if (this.tarea > prioridad) {
      return this.tarea; 
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  },
    
      
    }
```

Me da error. Para empezar a entender: ¿Es adecuado usar *get* aquí? ¿Le tengo que pasar parámetros? ¿O, tal vez, se resuelve diferente?

Comment: La clase debe definirse fuera de la función, de lo contrario, no será visible en otros contextos. Además, no queda claro para qué crear la clase `Empleado` y que "la función" (¿el constructor?) retorne la clase `Persona`.

Comment: la parte de la función ya viene en el ejercicio, tengo que resolverlo dentro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una clase es sólo syntactic sugar para una función, y el uso de [higher order functions](https://dev.to/damcosset/higher-order-functions-in-javascript-4j8b) para crear funciones al vuelo es común y poderoso. Lo importante es que **debes retornar la clase generada**, no simplemente declararla esperando que sea visible en el contexto global.

```
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
   return class Empleado {
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe=false) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe;
    }
   };
}
```

Una cosa que me llama la atención es que el enunciado dice:

- Crear una clase para construir objetos de tipo **Empleado**. (hasta aquí bien)
- Esta función debe retornar la clase **Persona**. (¿Persona o Empleado?)

Entonces se me ocurre que la idea de fondo es que `crearClaseEmpleado` se interprete como "crear al vuelo una clase que extiende Empleado". ¿Para qué? Por ejemplo para añadir los métodos `switchJefe` y `getTareasPrioritarias` a cualquier clase que se le pase a la función. como `Persona` extiende `Empleado`, se cumple que una instancia de `persona` es también un objeto de tipo `Empleado`.

```js
function crearClaseEmpleado(BaseClass) {
  return class Persona extends BaseClass {

    switchJefe() {
      this.jefe = !this.jefe;
    }
    getTareasPrioritarias(prioridad) {
      return this.tareas.filter(t => t.prioridad > prioridad);
    }

  };
}
class Empleado {
  constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe = false) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.salario = salario;
    this.tareas = tareas;
    this.jefe = jefe;
  }
}
let claseGenerada = crearClaseEmpleado(Empleado);

let persona = new claseGenerada('juanito', 4000, [{
  nombre: 'compras',
  prioridad: 4,
}, {
  nombre: 'operaciones',
  prioridad: 2,
}], true);



mocha.setup('bdd');

describe('test', () => {
  it('claseGenerada se llama "Persona"', () => {
    chai.expect(claseGenerada.name).to.equal('Persona');
  });
  it('claseGenerada instancia objetos de tipo Empleado', () => {
    chai.expect(persona).to.be.an.instanceof(Empleado);
  });

  it('Jefe es true', () => {
    chai.expect(persona.jefe).to.be.true;
  });
  it('Jefe se switchea a false', () => {
    persona.switchJefe();
    chai.expect(persona.jefe).to.be.false;
  });
  it('La tarea de prioridad>3 es "compras"', () => {
    chai.expect(persona.getTareasPrioritarias(3)).to.deep.equal([{
      nombre: 'compras',
      prioridad: 4,
    }]);

  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<!-- styling for the test results -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/3.1.0/mocha.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- container that will display test results -->
  <div id="mocha"></div>

  <!-- mocha (test runner) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/3.1.0/mocha.min.js"></script>

  <!-- chai (assertion library) -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.5.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```

Si estoy hilando muy fino con que la función extiende a otra, simplemente se puede declarar la clase completa dentro de la función:

```
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
  return class Empleado {
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe = false) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe;
    }
    switchJefe() {
      this.jefe = !this.jefe;
    }
    getTareasPrioritarias(prioridad) {
      return this.tareas.filter(t => t.prioridad > prioridad);
    }

  };
}
let Empleado = crearClaseEmpleado();
```

Pero en este caso la función no devuelve una clase "Persona" ni hay cómo testear que sea una instancia de Empleado sin que el test pierda todo sentido.

Answer (score 1):

No tiene sentido crear una función que devuelva una clase, principalmente porque no puedes proporcionar parámetros al constructor (al menos con lo poco que muestras en la pregunta) y se deben establecer los datos directamente dentro de la función.

```js
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
  class Empleado {
    // Si no se proporciona valor para jefe, por defecto será false
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe = false) { 
      this.nombre = nombre;    // Finaliza líneas con ;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe;  // Se establece valor del parámetro
    }
    // Método para cambiar valor de jefe
    switch = function() {
      // Intercambiar valor !true resulta en false y !false resulta en true
      this.jefe = !this.jefe;
    }
  }
  // Devolver una instancia de la clase con datos esperados según los mensajes de error
  return new Empleado('Maia', 4000, ['operaciones'], true);
}
const persona = crearClaseEmpleado();
console.log(persona.jefe);
// Cambiar valor de jefe
persona.switch();
console.log(persona.jefe);
```

De acuerdo al primer mensaje que obtienes:

> ● Clase › crearClaseEmpleado › should return a user constructor that correctly builds empleados objects

> `crearClaseEmpleado` debe devolver un constructor de usuario que correctamente construya objetos `empleados`;

Entonces no debe ser una función porque el constructor solo existe dentro de una clase y, en este caso, solo se puede devolver un objeto con la clase instanciada, no la clase como tal. De cualquier forma, esto debe resolver los problemas expuestos:

```
   98 |         expect(persona.salario).toBe(4000);
   99 |         expect(persona.tareas).toEqual(['operaciones']);
> 100 |         expect(persona.jefe).toEqual(true);
```

**Adicionalmente:** ¿Es obligatoria la función? Supongamos que sí, pero no es obligatorio que la clase esté definida ahí mismo y, de hecho, tendría mayor utilidad.

```js
// La clase de define fuera de la función, en contexto global
class Empleado {
    // Si no se proporciona valor para jefe, por defecto será false
    constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe = false) { 
      this.nombre = nombre;    // Finaliza líneas con ;
      this.salario = salario;
      this.tareas = tareas;
      this.jefe = jefe;  // Se establece valor del parámetro
    }
    // Método para cambiar valor de jefe
    switch = function() {
      // Intercambiar valor !true resulta en false y !false resulta en true
      this.jefe = !this.jefe;
   }
}

// La función sigue devolviendo una instancia de la clase
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
  // Devolver una instancia de la clase con datos esperados según los mensajes de error
  return new Empleado('Maia', 4000, ['operaciones'], true);
}
// Todo sigue funcionando exactamente igual
const persona = crearClaseEmpleado();
console.log(persona.jefe);
// Cambiar valor de jefe
persona.switch();
console.log(persona.jefe);
```

Con esto ya quedas preparada para aplicar cualquier corrección necesaria. En caso de ser obligatoria la función, ahí la tienes, de lo contrario, solo la eliminas y se puede instanciar la clase directamente.

**Notas finales:**

En cuanto a los otros errores, son materia para otra pregunta, de lo contrario, esto se va a hacer muy extenso y, aparte, la estructura de tareas difiere mucho de la forma en que se crean aquí.

Debes resolver primero esto, aplicar las correcciones necesarias y, solo entonces, tratar de continuar con las tareas prioritarias.

Answer (score 0):

En el primer ejercicio la funcion `crearClaseEmpleado` debe retornar un empleado o persona, puedes llamar a esta misma funcion y como retorna el empleado puedes almacenarlo en una constante o hace lo que quieras con el, espero se haya entendió, fíjate si pasas los tests

```
function crearClaseEmpleado() {
  // Crear una clase para construir objetos de tipo Empleado.
  // el constructor debe recibir:
  // nombre (string) , salario (integer) , tareas (array de objetos), jefe (booleano - por defecto false) 
  // Esta funcion debe retornar la clase Persona.
    class Empleado {
        constructor(nombre, salario, tareas, jefe) { 
            this.nombre = nombre,
            this.salario = salario,
            this.tareas = tareas, 
            this.jefe = false
       }
    }
  
   return new Empleado("Jose",4000, ['operaciones'], true)
}

const persona = crearClaseEmpleado()
console.log(persona)
```